Modification of Oxford MAT 2020 Q2
Created by: MeThe original Oxford MAT 2020 can be found here.

Consider the functions $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, $g:\mathbb Z_+\to\mathbb Z_+$ and $h:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ that are defined as$$\begin{align}f(n):=&\;2n+1\\g(n):=&\;5n-4\\h(n):=&\;3n^2+2\end{align}$$Let $\mathbb S$ be the set of numbers $n\in\mathbb N$ that can be achieved by applying, in some order, a combination of the functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ to the number 0. How many numbers $\le8192$ are in $\mathbb S$?

Hint:

Consider the binary representations of these numbers. What transformations do the coefficients of $f(n)$ and $h(n)$ represent? Could you work out something similar for the coefficients of $g(n)$?


$g(0)$ isn’t a natural number…

@Pranay $g(0)$ doesn't have to be a natural number. That just means that $g(0)\not\in\mathbb S$.

Do you know a nice solution?

But $g:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, which makes $g$ ill-defined.

@xnor I'm aware of a solution

@Pranay I'll edit the question then, it should probably $g:\mathbb Z_+\to\mathbb Z_+$. Thanks for pointing that out

Just to make sure: you could define $g’:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ as $g’(n)=5n+1$ instead of $g$ without affecting anything. Am I right?

@Pranay I believe not, since $f(0)=g(0)=1$ now. There's also probably a lot else that's affected (due to the $+1$ being there instead of the $-4$), although if anything I don't really care if $g$ is a function $g:\mathbb Z_+\to\mathbb Z_+$ or if it's $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.
